# Usage ROLLBACK TO SAVEPOINT with condition

Tags: sql, postgresql, case, savepoints

Is it possible to `ROLLBACK TO SAVEPOINT` with CASE?
My query is

```
BEGIN;
SAVEPOINT my_savepoint;
INSERT INTO DPoint (uuid) VALUES ('5547f4b7-00b3-4aac-8ceb-c9ca163a0214')
ON CONFLICT (uuid) DO NOTHING;
WITH
 ins1 AS (INSERT INTO Point (latitude, longitude, srid)
VALUES (37.251667, 14.917222, 4326) RETURNING id),
 ins2 as (INSERT INTO SPoint (idPt, uuiddpt)
     VALUES ((SELECT id FROM ins1), '5547f4b7-00b3-4aac-8ceb-c9ca163a0214') RETURNING id),
 ins3 as (INSERT INTO Distance (idSpt, uuiddpt)
     VALUES ((SELECT id FROM ins2), '5547f4b7-00b3-4aac-8ceb-c9ca163a0214'))
INSERT INTO DPointTS (uuid, type, name, idPoint)
VALUES ('5547f4b7-00b3-4aac-8ceb-c9ca163a0214', NULL, NULL, (SELECT id FROM ins1));

SELECT CASE WHEN
(SELECT uuid FROM DPoint
WHERE uuid = '5547f4b7-00b3-4aac-8ceb-c9ca163a0214' )
is not NULL THEN ROLLBACK TO SAVEPOINT my_savepoint END;
COMMIT;
```

***My idea is:***

When trying to insert once again DPoint.uuid = '5547f4b7-00b3-4aac-8ceb-c9ca163a0214', it is no need to insert Point, SPoint, Distance, DPointTS. So I would like to ROLLBACK these insertions to my_savepoint in transaction. Maybe any idea in what way I have to rewrite my code?

**EDIT:**

```
SELECT uuid IS NULL AS is_not_uuid FROM DPoint WHERE uuid = '5547f4b7-00b3-4aac-8ceb-c9ca163a0214';
\gset
\if :is_not_uuid
    \echo 'insert row to DPoint'
    INSERT INTO DPoint (uuid) VALUES ('5547f4b7-00b3-4aac-8ceb-c9ca163a0214');
    ... 
    my INSERT query

\endif
```

I update my strategy without SAVEPOINTs - if SELECT query returns `TRUE` I evaluate all insertions. What way I am execute the query, only in command line? When trying in console.sql in DataGRIP it throws an error - it honestly execute all the rows and fails in `INSERT INTO DPoint (uuid)...` in case the point is already exists. I would like to execute the statements in one way

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you cannot do it like that.

You will have to write client code and use conditional processing.

For example with `psql`:

```
-- set the variable "want_rollback" to TRUE or FALSE
SELECT uuid IS NOT NULL AS want_rollback
FROM dpoint
WHERE uuid = '5547f4b7-00b3-4aac-8ceb-c9ca163a0214' \gset
\if :want_rollback
ROLLBACK TO SAVEPOINT my_savepoint;
\endif
```

See [the documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-psql.html) for details about `\if`:

> `\if expression`
>   `\elif expression`
>   `\else`
>   `\endif`
>
> This group of commands implements nestable conditional blocks. A conditional block must begin with an `\if` and end with an `\endif`. In between there may be any number of `\elif` clauses, which may optionally be followed by a single `\else` clause. Ordinary queries and other types of backslash commands may (and usually do) appear between the commands forming a conditional block.
>
> The `\if` and `\elif` commands read their argument(s) and evaluate them as a boolean expression. If the expression yields `true` then processing continues normally; otherwise, lines are skipped until a matching `\elif`, `\else`, or `\endif` is reached. Once an `\if` or `\elif` test has succeeded, the arguments of later `\elif` commands in the same block are not evaluated but are treated as false. Lines following an `\else` are processed only if no earlier matching `\if` or `\elif` succeeded.
>
> The `expression` argument of an `\if` or `\elif` command is subject to variable interpolation and backquote expansion, just like any other backslash command argument. After that it is evaluated like the value of an on/off option variable. So a valid value is any unambiguous case-insensitive match for one of: `true`, `false`, `1`, `0`, `on`, `off`, `yes`, `no`. For example, `t`, `T`, and `tR` will all be considered to be `true`.
>
> Expressions that do not properly evaluate to true or false will generate a warning and be treated as false.
>
> Lines being skipped are parsed normally to identify queries and backslash commands, but queries are not sent to the server, and backslash commands other than conditionals (`\if`, `\elif`, `\else`, `\endif`) are ignored. Conditional commands are checked only for valid nesting. Variable references in skipped lines are not expanded, and backquote expansion is not performed either.
>
> All the backslash commands of a given conditional block must appear in the same source file. If EOF is reached on the main input file or an \include-ed file before all local \if-blocks have been closed, then psql will raise an error.

The same page will also explain `\gset`.

Comment: Thank you for the fast answer! Will you please give me more details about conditional processing? I didn't catch about using want_rollback, \gset...

Comment: I have added some documentation.

Comment: `\if` only works in `psql`. If you are working in a different environment, you have to use the programming language available in that environment.